# Javascript .live error

Tags: javascript, jquery

After upgrading jquery i get an error.
when i executed following javascript i get the error ther $(...).live is not a function. How can i fix this?

```
$(function(){
$('input[type=text]').live('focus',function(e){

    $(this).get(0).focus();
    $(this).get(0).select();

    //$(this).val('');
});

$('.blogImageSmall').bind('click', function(e){
    var oldHref = $('#blogImageLink').attr('href');
    var oldSrc = $('#blogImageLink').find('img').attr('src');

    $('#blogImageLink').attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));
    $('#blogImageLink').find('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('rel'));

    $(this).attr('href', oldHref);
    $(this).attr('rel', oldSrc); // .replace('150_', '35_')
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', oldSrc.replace('150_', '35_'));

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

// preload image:
var img = new Image(16,11);
img.src = '/images/ajax-loader.gif';
});
```

Comment: `.live()` was deprecated and they removed it in jQuery 1.9 [link](http://api.jquery.com/live/). You can use `.on()` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.live()` API has been deprecated for a long time. You can get the effect of

```
$("some selector").live("event", function() { ... })
```

by rewriting it as

```
$(document).on("event", "some selector", function() { ... })
```

The callback (event handler) function need not change for that transformation, though if your jQuery code is old enough it may be that there are other anachronisms in the function(s).

The problem with `.live()` was that the initial call to build the jQuery object was an almost completely wasted effort. That is, in

```
$("some selector").live( ... )
```

before the call to `.live()` could be made, jQuery would of course actually perform the DOM search for "some selector".  After that, `.live()` would pay no attention to what the library found in the DOM and just use the selector string itself to establish the delegated event handler (and that part of the behavior is essentially what `.on()` does). The new API lets you do the same things as `.live()` allowed, plus it's actually *more* flexible because you can control where in the DOM to place your delegated event handlers. (Usually, `document` is fine, but sometimes you might want finer-grained control.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'live' use 'on'. 'live' is deprecated listener from jquery version 1.9 I think